# Reduction of loop integrals in FeynCalc

Tags: packages, options, feyncalc

I'd like to use the PaVeReduce function within FeynCalc in Mathematica to reduce a triangle integral down to bubbles and tadpoles. I found the wolfram help page about this function but I did not find what all the options meant with the result that I was unable to produce the reduction I wanted. Has anyone used this function in FeynCalc before?

I have used other software for this reduction and I know what the answer is so I'm just playing about with FeynCalc at the moment. I tried

```
 PaVeReduce[C0[0, m^2, m^2/y, 0, 0, m^2]] // TraditionalForm
```

but this didn't do the required reduction.  I played about with the options too in

```
 SetOptions[PaVeReduce, A0ToB0 -> True, BReduce -> True, Collecting -> True, Dimension -> True, FCVerbose -> False, Factoring -> Factor2, IsolateNames -> False, Mandelstam -> {}, PaVeAutoReduce -> True, PaVeOrderList -> {}, WriteOutPaVe -> True]
```

but couldn't get the reduction to go ahead.

Thanks for any comments! There is also the possibility that I am using the wrong function because I know that Pass-Velt prescription is usually done for the reduction of tensor to scalar integrals and I'm trying to do a scalar to sum of simpler scalar integrals reduction.

Comment: Best to ask here: https://feyncalc.github.io/forum

Comment: If you use [*Package*-X](http://packagex.hepforge.org), and use the expansion pack `PVReduce`, you can get *some* result with `PVReduce[PVC[0, 0, 0, 0, m^2, m^2/y, 0, 0, m], "IRDivCToB" -> True]`.

Comment: @QuantumDot Thanks! I see that to use PVReduce I need to request the download from the website, did I understand that correctly? Actually Package-X in itself might be good enough for what I want, does this package allow one to input a given scalar loop integral evaluated in dim reg say and get an analytic expression for it to all orders in epsilon?

Comment: I've been looking for software that will provide me with the analytic expression for a scalar integral, not some numerical evaluation but rather the analytic expression to all orders in epsilon.

Comment: *Package*-X does give analytic expressions, but not all orders in epsilon. So maybe you need `PVReduce`; then you can insert the all orders expression yourself after reducing.

Comment: @QuantumDot I see, so does Package-X provide only the $\mathcal O (\epsilon^0)$ contribution or something?

Comment: Yes only O(eps)^0.

Comment: I see. So could you explain a little bit about why PVReduce would help getting an all orders expansion? Or did I misunderstand what you wrote?

Comment: Because, for your example, PVReduce seems to return a result containing only A0 and B0, and they have a simpler expression to all orders than the C0 which you can insert yourself.

Comment: Ah right, so you mean use PVReduce to reduce the triangle to A0 and B0, then input the all order expansions for A0 and B0 into this result, thereby giving the all order expansion for the triangle? I've seen the all order expansion for A0 in the literature but not for all the bubbles, but at least this is something for me to go on, thanks.

Comment: That’s right.  By the way, not all C0 can be reduced to A0 and B0.  Your case is special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the [Package-X](http://packagex.hepforge.org) expansion pack `PVReduce` to reduce Passarino-Veltman functions.

```
<<X`
<<PVReduce`

PVReduce[PVC[0, 0, 0, 0, m^2, m^2/y, 0, 0, m], "IRDivCToB" -> True]
```

[image]

`PVReduce` gives results that are correct to all orders in `ϵ`.  But be careful of the fact that the factors of `-4+d` in the denominator lead to `1/ϵ` poles multiplying the Passarino-Veltman functions.